# Транспортирование матрицы в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

Необходимо написать программу, которая транспонирует квадратную матрицу.

На вход программе подаётся натуральное число n — количество строк и столбцов в матрице, затем элементы матрицы.

Input:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Программа должна вывести транспонированную матрицу.

Output:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: А это задача не из stepik случаем?

Comment: @Man4soul да это задача из курса в stepik по python

Comment: Т.е. пару циклов , перемещающих элементы в нужные места, не судьба было написать? Нахрена тогда вообще учиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ на вашу задачу

```
n = int(input())
matrix = [list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
for i in zip(*matrix):
    print(*i)
```